# Concatenating strings using plus signs in a parameterized query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I want to ask how to implement something like this in SQL

```
String updateUserDocs1 = "UPDATE USERDOCS SET VIEW_DOCS = VIEW_DOCS + ' ' + ? WHERE USER_ID = ?";
```

It returns a java sql syntax error. encountered: "WHERE" at line 1

The statement appears to be syntactically correct. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please clarify what you expect there? I see two bind parameters; the first is truly odd. What is `SET VIEW_DOCS = VIEW_DOCS + ' ' + ?` supposed to do? Append something to `VIEW_DOCS`?

Comment: yes i want to add to the existing record in VIEW_DOCS column, sorry i wasn't very clear on the intent. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Try using `||` instead of `+` as your string concatenation operator. It seems to be working for me.

Comment: @GordThompson. Tried it. It's still the same error.

Comment: `UPDATE USERDOCS SET VIEW_DOCS = VIEW_DOCS || ' ' || ? WHERE id = ?` works for me with "derby-10.14.1.0.jar". What version of Derby are you using?

Comment: Hi, @GordThompson. thanks for the quick replies! Im currently using version 10.11.1.2

Comment: 10.11.1.2 is not available from Maven Central, but my [test code](https://pastebin.com/PmBT6f3D) also works with 10.11.1.1.

Comment: I was missing a ||. it's A okay now. thank you very much

Comment: Since this problem is now fixed, please consider deleting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many SQL dialects support an overload of the `+` operator for string concatenation, but the ANSI SQL standard string concatenation operator is `||`.

With Derby, the code

```java
sql = "UPDATE USERDOCS SET VIEW_DOCS = VIEW_DOCS + ' ' + ? WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

results in the following error

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The '+' operator with a left operand type of 'VARCHAR' and a right operand type of 'CHAR' is not supported.

However,

```java
sql = "UPDATE USERDOCS SET VIEW_DOCS = VIEW_DOCS || ' ' || ? WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

works correctly.

Comment: This explained why || works but + doesn't. Thank you!